# How to update the translation (Vue-i18n) in the store (Vuex)?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, translation, vue-i18n

Translations that are statically added to the store are not updated after updating the locale.

`i18n.locale = 'fr';`

I don't understand how to fix this.
Any thoughts?

*All that I could find on the Internet on this issue is [HERE](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n/issues/415).
But I still do not understand their solution, if it is there.*

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import i18n from './js/i18n';
import store from './store/index';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

i18n.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

import en from '../../locales/en.json';
import fr from '../../locales/fr.json';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: 'en',
  messages: { en, fr },
});
```

store.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import i18n from '@/js/i18n';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    qqq: [{
      id: 'yes',
      name: i18n.t('yes'), // this not changes
    }, {
      id: 'no',
      name: i18n.t('no'), // this not changes
    }]
  },

  actions: {
    async GET_USER({ state }, context, payload) {
      // get locale from server
      // bla bla request by server


      // change locale
      i18n.locale = 'fr';
    },
  }
```

Comment: your store's state isn't reactive.  it would be better to just store `'yes'` or `'no'` and then call `i18n.t(state.name)` where needed.

Comment: @yoduh

Hello. I know that the store is not reactive, the question is: how to get around this situation more elegantly and simply?

Comment: I've told you.  Translating should be done in the components.  You should keep the default locale strings in your store and only translate right before rendering to the UI.